# Shortening SQL Statement

Tags: google-sheets

I've managed to get the info I need in Google sheets by using the following query:

```
SELECT A,B,C WHERE G contains date '"&TEXT(J$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or H contains date '"&TEXT(J$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or I contains date '"&TEXT(J$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or J contains date '"&TEXT(J$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or K contains date '"&TEXT(J$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
```

but is some way of compressing this at all?

EG:

```
`SELECT A,B,C WHERE G OR H OR I OR J OR K contains date '"&TEXT(J$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'`
```

Comment: Maybe something like `... WHERE CONCATENATE(G,",",H,",",I,",",J,",",K) CONTAINS ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of below-

```
=FILTER(A:C,ArrayFormula(MMULT(--(G:K=J1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(G:K)))))
```

Or `QUERY()` function like-

```
=QUERY({A:C,ArrayFormula(MMULT(--(G:K=J1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(G:K))))},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col4>0")
```